# Why not getting any writting

Tags: c, operating-system

i was doing a homework of C for school and i have a little problem .
here i want to read a file and display it in the terminal
the catch is the buffer size needs to be controlled and not equal to the size of the file
and even without that i was trying to make it work with the size and it didn't, i think because of an infinite loop because when i run the commande nothing happens and i don't get to write other command
here is my code :

```
void cat(int size, const char * path){
    char *buf = malloc(size);
    int fd = open(path , O_RDONLY) ;
    off_t taille = lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END) ;
    int n = 0 ;
    lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET) ;
    while(n<taille){
      n+= read(fd,buf + n , taille -n-1 ) ;
    }
    write(STDOUT_FILENO , buf , taille) ;

}
```

Thank You in advance .

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is size of memory allocated for `buf` and what size do you actually use? Does that match?

Comment: First thing to do: add errr checking, especially check if `open` succeeds. Also read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: @Gerhardh exactly they asked us to control that and not " just make it the size of the file which it would've been better "

Comment: @Jabberwocky yeah i usually do that in the end of program  . i like to make the algorithme work that do the checking .

Comment: You did not get the point of that assignment. You allocate a buffer that is smaller but then you behave as if it was same size. You are using it beyond the limit you are allowed to. You are not allowed to access any memory beyond `buf[size-1]`.

Comment: @Gerhardh so you are telling me if size was just the size of my file it would work normally ? well they asked us to do it with a size u give and not just the size of a file

Comment: Yes, they asked you to do it but you refuse to do it. You probably cause some segfault or other crash before your program can start to output anything. You must rework your loop to read data and include writing data into same loop.

Comment: @Gerhardh i m not very experienced with what you are saying , tho i understand the part of using beyond memory i ve just changed it and made buf = malloc(lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END) ) which is the size of file but i still get the same thing like it's an infinite loop , can u suggest me anything else ?

Comment: No. You shall not use a buffer fitting the whole file. That is what yor assignment tells you.

Comment: @Gerhardh any suggestion for what can i change ?

Answer (score 3):

You are causing undefined behaviour by accessing memory you are not allowed to touch.

```c
void cat(int size, const char * path){
    char *buf = malloc(size);
    int fd = open(path , O_RDONLY) ;
    off_t taille = lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END) ;
    int n = 0 ;
    lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET) ;
    while(n<taille){
      n+= read(fd,buf + n , taille -n-1 ) ;  // << buf can hold only up to size bytes.
    }
    write(STDOUT_FILENO , buf , taille) ;
}
```

For any `file_size > size` this leads to illegal access of memory which may cause segfault or any other abort before you start writing any output.

As your assignment explicitly tells you not to put the whole file in a buffer, You need to handle the file I/O in chunks:

```c
void cat(int size, const char * path) {
    char *buf = malloc(size);      // TODO: Add check for NULL
    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY); // TODO: Add check for < 0
    off_t taille = lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END);
    int n = 0;
    lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);

    while (n<taille) {
      ssize_t readbytes = read(fd, buf, size);
      write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, readbytes);
      n += readbytes;
    }
    fclose(fd);
}
```

or simpler:

```c
void cat(int size, const char * path) {
    char *buf = malloc(size);      // TODO: Add check for NULL
    ssize_t fd = open(path, O_RDONLY); // TODO: Add check for < 0

    ssize_t readbytes;
    while ((readbytes = read(fd,buf , size)) > 0) {
      write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, readbytes);
    }
    // TODO: check for readbytes < 0
    fclose(fd);
}
```

Code is not tested.

Comment: well actually we are not allowed to do read and write both  in loops we are allowed only to call write once so we minimize the maximum the system calls so it won't cost a lot of calculations or at least what our teacher asked us to do

Comment: You already do reads in a loop. You cannot deal with both requirements. Either you need a big buffer holding everything or you need to do it in smaller chunks. Avoiding both is not possible. Besides that you should always state the full set of rules and not come up with additional contraints afterwards.

Comment: that's what i thought , so thank you ! and as i told you even when i allocated enough memory it still the same problem and didn't work would you have an idea of what causing it ? and excuse me for not saying everything from the beginning it's my first time publishing here ^^

Comment: If your code does not run when you allocate a large enough buffer, you need to start using a debugger and step through your code. Then see what values your variables have and what you expect.

Comment: @Gerherdh alright ! thank you for your time and help